# Linear Algebra Done Right Example 1.7

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

In the book Linear Algebra Done Right I came across this example for the sum of vector spaces.

[image]

Did he say the second $W + U$ is still equal to 1.7 because it doesn't matter whether you say $(x+y, y, 0)$ or $(x, y, 0)$ or am I missing something? It seems like this notation can get confusing if that is the case.

Thanks,

Jackson

Comment: Yes, this is what he is saying.

Comment: This is because $(x,y,0)$ can be written as $(x'+y,y,0)$ for some $x'$: just set $x'=x-y$.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trouble understanding Sum of Subspaces](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/890215/trouble-understanding-sum-of-subspaces)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It *does* matter whether you say $(x + y, y, 0)$ or $(x, y, 0)$ on the level of *individual* vectors. But when you consider the collections \begin{align*}
\{(x, y, 0)&: x, y \in \Bbb F^3\} \quad \text{and} \\
\{(x + y, y, 0)&:x, y \in \Bbb F^3\}\end{align*}

the *individual* differences get wiped away; the two sets are equal, as *collections* of vectors (as others have pointed out).

For a concrete example using $\Bbb F = \Bbb R$, it's easy to see that $(2, 3, 0)$ is in the first set. But it's slightly less easy to see that that we can write $\big(2, 3, 0\big)$ as $\big((-1) + 3, 3, 0\big)$, and thus it belongs in the second set as well. Perhaps vowing to use different variables, i.e., writing the second set as $\{(x' + y', y', 0): x', y' \in \Bbb F^3\}$ will help you ignore the *individual* differences.

It *can* be confusing, and it can take some getting used to. Linear algebra is often a transition into higher math classes, so it's good you're paying attention to, and coping with, these details now!

Answer (score 6):

Writing 
$$\{(x+y,y,0) \in F^3 \mid x,y \in F\}$$
is redundant because the first coordinate takes on all values in $F$ independently of $y$. This is because for any $\eta, y \in F$, we can find an $x$ such that $x+y = \eta$.