# Sum of subsets in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am working with subspaces and using Linear Algebra done right as literature. Axler defines the sum of subsets as:

> Suppose $U_1,...,U_m$ are subsets of V. The **sum** of $U_1,...,U_m$, denoted $U_1+\cdots+U_m$, is in the set of all possible sums of elements of $U_1,...,U_m$. More precisely,
>   $$U_1+\cdots+U_m=\{u_1+\cdots+u_m:u_1\in U_1,\dots,u_m\in U_m\}$$

Now suppose that $U = \{(x,x,y,y)\in\mathbb{F}^4:x,y\in\mathbb{F}\}$ and $W = \{(x,x,x,y)\in\mathbb{F}^4:x,y\in\mathbb{F}\}$. Then:

$$U+W=\{(x,x,y,z)\in\mathbb{F}^4:x,y,z\in\mathbb{F}\}$$

When I try to verify the assertion I get:

$$U+W = \{(x+x,x+x,x+y,y+y):x,y\in\mathbb{F}\}$$

I just apply the definition of the sum of subsets. What am I missing?
Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: You shouldn't use the same $x,y$ for both $U,W$. Rather, use different letters for one to be fair. You ought to look at $(x,x,y,y)+(a,a,a,b)$ to understand what typical element in sum looks like.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/890215/trouble-understanding-sum-of-subspaces?rq=1
does this answer your question?

Comment: @SeanThrasher, I read that several times before posting but unfortunately it didn't click for me.

Answer (score 4):

I also had trouble understanding this one, but I think it all comes down to how you name the elements of the set.

As in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/890215/trouble-understanding-sum-of-subspaces?rq=1), and [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2747591/sum-of-subsets-in-linear-algebra#comment5668981_2747591), we can use different letters for one of the sets. Let's suppose that $U = \{(x,x,y,y)\in\mathbb{F}^4:x,y\in\mathbb{F}\}$ and $W = \{(v,v,v,w)\in\mathbb{F}^4:v,w\in\mathbb{F}\}$.

Now, we get the same as your result:

$$U+W = \{(x+v,x+v,y+v,y+w):x,y,v,w\in\mathbb{F}\}$$

Then, by setting $x=x+v$, $y=y+v$, $z=y+w$, we have

$$U+W = \{(x, x, y, z):x,y,z\in\mathbb{F}\}$$

Which is what the book directly states.

Comment: Is there not supposed to be a $z$ at the end?